# MS SQL Server How to get a list with user login in the last six months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query that extracts a list of the last six months with the distinct user logins from a table with two columns.

```
User_Name  |Login_Date
-----------|----------
vossos@Msad|11/12/2020
```

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct user logins"? What exactly do you mean by "last six months"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
SELECT User_Name 
       , MAX(Login_Date) as LastLoginDate
FROM yourtable
WHERE Login_Date >= SELECT DATEADD(MONTH , -6 , GETDATE())
GROUP BY User_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "distinct user login" you mean the distinct values in the first column, just use `select distinct` and by "last six months" you mean exactly six months before the current date/time, then:

```
select distinct user_loigc
from t
where login_date > dateadd(month, -6, getdate());
```